# How to remove border of Eclipse SWT Table

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, border

I am adding a SWT Table in Eclipse Form, but I want to remove the outer border of the Table.
How to do the needful.

[image]

Above is the Table I created, But I dont want the Boundary/Border around it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the case, but from the picture the outer border looks like the one painted when SWT.Border flag is used. Maybe you are adding your table to composite that has this flag used as style constant. Remove this constant and the outer border will be gone

Answer (score 1):

This border is rendered even if you don't use `SWT.BORDER`.
But if there is no `TableColumn`, no border is rendered.
Just remove `TableColumn`, if you want to remove border.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for `SWT.BORDER` and replace it with something else, like `SWT.NONE`

It could be where you create the table or the container.